# Usage of "granularities" (in plural form)

Tags: word-usage, grammatical-number

I wonder whether it is correct to use the word "granularity" in its plural form.

For example:

> 1. X and Y are commonly used **granularities** in Z research.
> 2. This study can be conducted at both coarse and fine **granularities**.
> 3. This study can be conducted at different **granularities**.

Can I use "granularities" in the above sentences? Or can I simply use the singular form "granularity"?

Comment: Apparently, you do not really mean *granuralities,* but rather, 'levels/ degrees of granurality.'  That should solve the issue.

Comment: (From my experience in medical imaging research) In technical jargon it's quite common and correct for *granularity* to be used in this way. So, it depends a bit on where you're going to use the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

As the two commenters both correctly assert, there is more than one reading for your use of the word.

Accordingly, if you are referring to an arbitrary unit, then the phrase *levels of granularity* is more appropriate.

Conversely if *granularity* is shorthand for a specific grain size, such as in sand/sediment samples, or the salt grain size associated with photosensitive films of differing ISO levels (or their digital equivalents, such as in medical imaging), then *granularities* is perfectly acceptable.